# Fluid Sim looks rough even with a high resolution division

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am simulation a water inside of a glass. the issue is the sides of the fluid where it touches the glass object (the collision object) the fluid looks rought [image: this is a picture] ;
I tried applying subdivision on both inflow object and collision object but it didn't help.

[project blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uiD2hIDVO0yXCQbvyupFyUSn5ttH-j-W/view?usp=share_link)